# Does intel E7400 Core2Duo support vt-x?

Tags: intel-core2, vt-x

Does intel E7400 Core2Duo support vt-x? The [specification on the intel's website](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=36500#ordering) says it supports vt-x,

But the Intel Processor Identification utility says it doesn't

http://6point9.in/Capture.JPG

Can anyone confirm this?

I am using [Gigagbyte G31MS2L Motherboard](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=2693#ov)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the CPU's Spec Code?

Your first link shows that there are different versions of the E7400, with the SLGW3 having VT-x, while the SLB9Y and SLGQ8 do not.

Try using a program like [CPU-Z](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/cpu-z.html) to see which one you have.

Comment: Ok. Mine is SLB9Y. :|